# Can I justify my text when I create a docx file with Quarto?

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, quarto

I have been using `quarto` in R for a few days.

I need to generate an `.docx` with justified text and Times New Roman font.

To justify in `.rmd` files I put `<div style="text-align: justify">` at the begin of the file and close with `</div>`.

But this is not working with `quarto`. How can I fix it?

Also, how can I change my main font in `quarto`?

My code:

```
---
title: "My simple title"
description: | 
  Text proof
author: "My name and ID"
format: 
  docx:
    geometry: 
      - top=30mm
      - left=30mm
editor: visual
---

<div style="text-align: justify"> 

**UNIVERSIDADE DE SÃO PAULO - USP**

-   Program

-   Date: 10/05/2022

-   Subject: Calc

-   Professor: Marcelo 

# Question
**1)** Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textxt textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textxt textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved with https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/ms-word-templates.html

First you create a reference .docx and define the style of your document, like title, author, first paragraph, etc.

Than you add at your .qmd

```
format:
  docx:
    reference-doc: custom-reference-doc.docx
```